# Variables as Route Parameters (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-parameters

I am looking for some help,

I have a bunch of  tags that I would like to make dynamic by using variables for the routing:

blade snippet:

```php
<div class="project-card">
   <a href="{{ route('title', ['project' => '1978-reel-boom'], app()->getLocale() ) }}" >
      <img alt="1978 Reel Boom" title="1978 Reel Boom" src="{image}">
      <p>1978 Reel Boom</p>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="project-card">
   <a href="{{ route('title', ['project' => '1979-cubus-diebach'], app()->getLocale() ) }}" >
      <img alt="1979 Cubus Diebach" title="1979 Cubus Diebach" src="{image}">
      <p>1979 Cubus Diebach</p>
   </a>
</div>
```

My route looks like this:

```php
Route::get('architectuur/{project}', ['as' => 'title', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ArchitectureController@showProject'])->name('title');
```

but I am getting this error:

[image: laravel error message (img)]

the idea would be that I could make a single blade page that will respond to the title and display a carousel with images from that project according to the title. (no databases)

Comment: Did you try to clear routes cache? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I have just tried it, the result didn't change.

Comment: does the route show up when you do `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: `|   GET|HEAD   |   {language}/architectuur/   |   architectuur `
`|   GET|HEAD   |   {language}/architectuur/{project}   |   title `

Those are the routes that are shown in my terminal

Comment: Please share whole route file.

Comment: @Shahrukh, here is my Gist: https://gist.github.com/basileLeroy/ce69e0d0b17871f1be207f6faacb8216 .. and now with the actual routing list in it*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just define the name of your route, there is no need to add `as`.

```
Route::get('architectuur/{project}',  'App\Http\Controllers\ArchitectureController@showProject')
    ->name('title');
```

Comment: I also tried using it this way, I got a different error message saying: 
Missing required parameter for [Route: title] [URI: {language}/architectuur/{project}] [Missing parameter: language].

language beeing my localisation prefix on my pages (the project routes are inside that route group

Comment: That is another problem. You can set a default value for your url. Read more [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values)

Comment: Ah I see, I will have a look at that! thank you very much.